# Clojure QL : running plain SQL queries

Tags: mysql, postgresql, clojure, clojureql

are there any ways to perform the following queries in clojureql ? :

- insert into table1(id, name, age) select id, name, age from table2
- create table t1 (id int, name varchar(50), age varchar(100));
- drop table table3;
- analyze table4;

or is there any work around to running these ? even if I need another library to do it, that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClojureQL is mainly for querying. There is some support for insert `(conj! table records)` and delete `(disj! table predicate)`, but the main thing it does is to provide an interface to SQL based on the relational operators `project`,`select` and `rename`.

To do the queries you're asking for, you can drop into `clojure.java.jdbc`, which ClojureQL uses under the hood.

First of all, the DDL commands can be done with help from the `clojure.java.jdbc.ddl` namespace:

```
;; create table t1 (id int, name varchar(50), age varchar(100));
(execute! db 
  (create-table :t1 
    [:id :int] 
    [:name "VARCHAR(50)"] 
    [:age "VARCHAR(100)"])

;; drop table table3;
(execute! db 
  (drop-table :table3)
```

I don't think there's syntactic support for the other two operations you have there, but you can probably just send a raw query to the database like so.

```
(execute! db 
   ["insert into table1(id, name, age) select id, name, age from table2"])
```

If you're doing a lot of migration/ddl-y type things, I think there are some libraries with a bit more syntactic support out there, because `clojure.java.jdbc.ddl` "intentionally has a very minimal DDL syntax". (Perhaps [Lobos](https://github.com/budu/lobos) or [Ragtime](https://github.com/weavejester/ragtime)?)